# Android: camera frame resolution larger than 640x480

Tags: android, opencv, camera, android-camera

In Android you need to set a Surface to the camera so that you get a preview. But camera preview is only supported [up to 640x480](http://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2304). I tried using OpenCV and VideoCapture in C++ (Android NDK) but higher resolution did not work either.

So, is there a way to request camera frames in higher resolutions (for example 1024x768 - which is supported by the camera) and process those frames without actually displaying them?

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: The Android camera can most certainly support previews higher than 640x480. It is possible that certain devices' cameras cannot support higher than that, but many newer devices do. I have written [a library to support camera use in apps](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera), and I have tested it on many devices, and I have not run into a 640x480 preview limitation.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out it's a combination of the ImageFormat and the resolution. I need to set correct Imageformat.YUY2, resolution (for example to 2592x1944) and framerate (here 3FPS) to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that it's a combination of the ImageFormat and the resolution. You need to set correct Imageformat.YUY2, resolution (for example to 2592x1944) and framerate (here 3FPS) to get it working. But preview should generally be in a lower resolution.